# MongoDB C# Driver connection pooling

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the current stable version of the MongoDB C# Driver. I have a long-running service essentially reads data from an external source and writes it all to a MongoDB database.

At the moment, I handle this by connecting to MongoDB on startup...

```
void Connect()
{
    var client = new MongoClient("(url)");
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var db = server.GetDatabase("(db-name)");
    this.coll = db.GetCollection("(collection-name)");
}
```

and then whenever I get some data, I simply do:

```
void Insert(object data)
{
    this.coll.Save(data);
}
```

This all works fine, except for the odd occasion where the connection to MongoDB fails. I then an IOException on the Save call.

So I want to add some resilience to this, and the natural thing to do is to catch the IOException, try to re-connect, and then retry the Save. However, I'm wondering if I can make use of the connection pool to automatically handle lost connections for me. If so, what would my code need to look like for connection pooling to work?

Comment: give the detail about the error. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446528/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-doesnt-release-connections-then-errors

Comment: The error isn't especially relevant - it lost connection to my database machine, which will happen from time to time. I just want to know what the best way to handle this is, and whether the connection pool can be utilized rather than writing the reconnection logic myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a connection pooling going on.  The problem with sockets is that you don't know if they work until you use them. You have to send data to see if the connection is broken. The driver heartbeats occasionally, so there is a good chance we'll find that the connections were broken and start them over. But, there is a good chance you'll attempt to do an operation prior to the heartbeat running and the discovery of the broken connection. In this case, you'll check out a connection we didn't know was bad and you'll get an exception. The only thing you can do is catch and retry.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that'd be the case. I wasn't sure if the 'try, else reconnect & retry else fail' would be built in somewhere when connection pooling was in use. I don't think my code above is taking advantage of any use of connection pooling since it only connects once. Presumably I'd have to bring the connect logic into the Insert method to do so?

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything to get connection pooling. It is simply always there. Your code is perfectly fine as is. If you just retry (and the server is back up), then the next attempt will succeed. Perhaps a little delay, but you don't need to "re-connect".

Comment: Craig Wilson, thank you. Bus this bahavior is soo magic and you need write it in docs, please.

Comment: I think this is documented here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/error_handling/#connection-errors-1, maybe not as specifically as this particular case, but it's certainly there.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the MongoClientSettings object is used to build a ClusterKey which differentiates one cluster from another (even a cluster of one in the case of a single instance).  Since the cluster contains the connection pool, you need to be careful that multiple clusters are not being accidentally initialized.

Using a single static MongoClientSettings helped me out of connection overload.

I opted to initialize new MongoClients with a single MongoClientSettings in order to report which server of the replica set I was currently connected to.